# Nested List Of Class Search Or Update Using Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, tree

How can I find class from nested list ?

I am working on trees and just want to retreive and add child based on id.

**Class**

```
 public class d3_mitch
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public List<d3_mitch> children { get; set; }
}
```

**Object Creation and Query**

```
 d3_mitch t = new d3_mitch();
        t.id = 1;
        t.type = "Root";
        t.name = "Animal";
        t.description = "A living organism that feeds on organic matter";
        t.children = new List<d3_mitch>() {


            new d3_mitch() { name = "Carnivores", type = "Type", id = 2, description = "Diet consists solely of animal materials",
            children=new List<d3_mitch>(){ new d3_mitch() { id= 3 ,name="Felidae",type="Family",description="Also known as cats"} }
            }

        };


        d3_mitch child = t.children.Where(x => x.id == 3).FirstOrDefault();

       //This return null because no direct child has has id = 3 but nested
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use recursion. Try next code

```
d3_mitch FindById(d3_mitch root, int id)
{
  if (root.id == id)
    return root;

  foreach (var child in root.children)
  {
    if (child.id == id)
      return child;

    var subTreeResult = FindById(child, id);
    if (subTreeResult != null)
      return subTreeResult;
  }

  // no such item
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SelectMany

```
 t.children.SelectMany(s => s.children)
  .FirstOrDefault(s => s.children.Any(d => d.id == 3));
```

Comment: sorry but this is not arrays of class thats why cannot implement "SelectMany"

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive method will resolve your problem.

```
    public static d3_mitch Find(d3_mitch main, int id)
    {
        if (main.id == id)
            return main;

        if (main.id != id && main.children != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in main.children)
            {
                return child.children.Any(x=>x.id==id)? child.children.First(x=>x.id==id) : Find(child, id);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: no it does not work because nested child could also have a nested child and so on.

Comment: Analyse correctly the code. It does work correctly! Have you tested it?I added a lot of records and it works

Comment: In case when there is no item with that id your code will always return first child. If there are no children nodes at all you always return root element, no matter does it id match

Comment: You can't just do `return Find` in the `foreach` loop. What if item we are looking for is second child? Store result in local variable, if it has non-null value we have found our desired item and can return it. If not, continue looping

Comment: Edited the response with the fix